# How to release the GPU memory used by Numba cuda?

Tags: python, cuda, numba

x_cpu, y_cpu, z_cpu are big numpy arrays with same length, Result is the Grid result that will reduce the x,y,z resolution and only keep one point in each grid, they cannot be put into GPU memory together.
so I divided x,y,z into several parts but still put the whole Result into the GPU memory used

```
from numba import cuda
from math import ceil

SegmentSize = 1000000
Loops = ceil(len(x_cpu),SegmentSize)
Result = cuda.device_array((maxX-minX,maxY-minY))
for lopIdx in range(Loops):
    x = cuda.to_device(x_cpu[lopIdx*SegmentSize:(lopIdx+1)*SegmentSize])
    y = cuda.to_device(y_cpu[lopIdx*SegmentSize:(lopIdx+1)*SegmentSize])
    z = cuda.to_device(z_cpu[lopIdx*SegmentSize:(lopIdx+1)*SegmentSize])
    CudaProc[blocks, 1024](x,y,z, Result)
    cuda.synchronize()
Result_CPU = Result.copy_to_host()
```

But when I did so, Unknown Cuda Error raised. I noticed that the occupied GPU memory kept raising.
I think it is because that in the loops, it keeps writing new x, y, z into the GPU memory without releasing the x,y,z before. I couldn't find much information about how to release the GPU memory. Can anyone help?

Comment: Allocate x,y, and z outside the loop and use copy_to_device within the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty much at the mercy of standard Python object life semantics and Numba internals (which are terribly documented) when it comes to GPU memory management in Numba. The best solution is probably to manage everything as explicitly as possible, which means not performing GPU object creation in things like loops unless you understand it will be trivial to performance and resource consumption.

I would suggest moving GPU array creation out of the loop:

```
from numba import cuda
from math import ceil

SegmentSize = 1000000
Loops = ceil(len(x_cpu),SegmentSize)
Result = cuda.device_array((maxX-minX,maxY-minY)) #you explicitly should type these
x = cuda.device_array(SegmentSize, dtype=dtype) #you explicitly should type these
y = cuda.device_array(SegmentSize, dtype=dtype) #you explicitly should type these
z = cuda.device_array(SegmentSize, dtype=dtype) #you explicitly should type these

for lopIdx in range(Loops):
    x.copy_to_device(x_cpu[lopIdx*SegmentSize:(lopIdx+1)*SegmentSize])
    y.copy_to_device(y_cpu[lopIdx*SegmentSize:(lopIdx+1)*SegmentSize])
    z.copy_to_device(z_cpu[lopIdx*SegmentSize:(lopIdx+1)*SegmentSize])
    CudaProc[blocks, 1024](x,y,z, Result)
    cuda.synchronize()
Result_CPU = Result.copy_to_host()
```

[ Code written in browser, never tested, use at own risk ]

That way you ensure that the memory is only allocated once and you reuse the same memory through all the loop trips. You still don't have explicit control of when the intermediate arrays will be destroyed, but this way it prevents running out of memory within the loop.

Comment: Great idea! I didn't know that there was a copy_to_device function! I think this is what I've been looking for! Appreciate it!

Comment: HI, I think that we are closer than ever except one last problem, all the previous loops work well, however the last one loop returns ValueError: incompatible shape: (14331033,) vs. (7235711,). I know exactly what caused it (The shapes don't match, of course), but I have no idea how to solve it. Any idea?

Comment: This sounds like a different question. I can't help you solve a problem in code I can't see. Perhaps accept this answer and ask a new question?

Comment: Sorry for my poor expression. This error happens because of the solution you proposed. As we can easily predict, the last processing segment can hardly be the same size with all the previous segments. If you set up the array before the loop and put data in during the loop, the last loop will return this error, because the data to be put in is not the same size with the preset device array.

Comment: @Crear -- (though probably you figured out by now) easiest is pass the bound separately and check that the thread is processing a legal value, and if not, do nothing.